# Samba share mounting in read-only mode

Tags: mount, samba, fstab

I used to mount my local network HDD (samba share) using following fstab entry:

```
//192.168.1.5/PUBLIC /media/MyBookLive smbfs credentials=/home/gacek/.mybookcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

Of course, the `.mybookcredentials` file contains authentication details for user with full rights. It used to work in 12.x, but I had to reinstall my Ubuntu and right now (in 11.10) it mounts the share in read-only mode.

I also tried to replace `smbfs` with `cifs` with no result.

How can I mount my samba share (via fstab) with write permissions?

**SOLVED**

OK, I haven't noticed that my GID changed. After checking my `UID` using:

```
id -u username
```

And replacing with it the UID and GID in `fstab` file all works - I have read-write permissions to my mounted samba disc.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the "defaults" option

```
//192.168.1.5/PUBLIC /media/MyBookLive cifs defaults,credentials=/home/gacek/.mybookcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

or the "rw" option.

```
//192.168.1.5/PUBLIC /media/MyBookLive cifs rw,credentials=/home/gacek/.mybookcredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

Comment: After adding defaults or rw it says that the line is incorrect

Comment: I just tested similar lines and had success, but only if I used 'cifs' instead of 'smbfs'. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, still it says there's some error. I found where was my mistake - see my update. so the question is solved